# PnP Location Control is not showing intelligence

Tags: spfx-webparts, custom, pnp

I am trying to use [Location Picker](https://pnp.github.io/sp-dev-fx-controls-react/controls/LocationPicker/) in my SPFx webpart and the suggestions are not working.

It gives 401 error for below API along with CORS error.

```
https://outlook.office365.com/SchedulingB2/api/v1.0/me/findmeetinglocations
```

Followed the same steps as the given in this [PnP Location Picker Control for SPFx](https://ravichandran.blog/2021/09/23/pnp-location-picker-control-for-spfx/) blog but getting below error.

[image]

Can anyone help here? the blog seems latest but still facing this issues.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue recently. After hours and hours of tests and investigation, I realized that the reason was due to lack of permission.

**Short Answer**

If you either

- debug the webpart with an account with enough permissions (in my case, I had this issue when I debugged with a non-admin account, and when I ran tests with an admin account, the issue disappeared).
- package the solution, deploy and install the webpart to the site

You won't have the error anymore.

**Investigate cause of the issue**

If you look at the source code of the component, you would see it tries to get a custom token for the request to the findmeetinglocations API

```
let response: SPHttpClientResponse = await this.props.context.spHttpClient.post(`${this.props.context.pageContext.web.serverRelativeUrl}/_api/SP.OAuth.Token/Acquire`, SPHttpClient.configurations.v1, spOpts);
let PrimaryQueryResult: any = await response.json();
this._token = PrimaryQueryResult.access_token;
```

*If you try to post the request (I used Insomia) with this token, you would see the request returns with successful response.*
[image]

And then it tries to post the request with a custom header, including the token received from above code

```
const requestHeaders: Headers = new Headers();
requestHeaders.append("Content-type", "application/json");
requestHeaders.append("Accept", "application/json");
requestHeaders.append("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
requestHeaders.append("Authorization", `Bearer ${this._token}`);
const spOpts: ISPHttpClientOptions = {
  body: `{"QueryConstraint":{"Query":"${searchText}"},"LocationProvider":32,"BingMarket":"en-IN"}`,
  headers: requestHeaders
};
let client1: AadHttpClient = await this.props.context.aadHttpClientFactory.getClient("https://outlook.office365.com");
let response1 = await client1.post("https://outlook.office365.com/SchedulingB2/api/v1.0/me/findmeetinglocations", AadHttpClient.configurations.v1, spOpts);
let json = await response1.json();
```

But here is the problem: **The post function drops the Authorization section from the requestHeader**.
If you look at the request header, you would find that the Bearer token is not the token that you assigned to it. The AadHttpClient post function requests its own token and stores it in the Session Storage
[image]
*If you replace the accessToken with the custom token from _api/SP.OAuth.Token/Acquire, the LocationPicker works again.*

**Conclusion**

After investigation, I think getToken() function of the LocationPicker has no effect as the token is not used at all.

I still haven't found a solution to prevent the post function from dropping the custom token and generating its own token, but I reckon this issue doesn't really matter since it won't appear in an installed webpart. The request won't fail even with non-admin account.

Comment: Hi Mark, many thanks for the detailed information. I am one of the maintainers of the controls repository and I have created an issue here:
https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-controls-react/issues/1149
The details you provided allowed me to fix the issue very quickly and a working beta release should be out later today.
Many thanks!